# LXML Xpath Query

Tags: python, lxml

I'm in the middle of writing a small and dirty module to convert an XML document to JSON so that various Javascript libraries can display it in a table. This involves me learning to use LXML and its various XPath functions.

I have the following block of code:

```py
    def parse(self):

        parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_comments=True, encoding="UTF-8", no_network=True, recover=True)
        root = etree.XML(self.text, parser=parser)
        self.tree = etree.XPathElementEvaluator(root)

        print(f"test: { self.tree('/*') }")
```

In my unit test, this outputs the following:

```
test_parse (test_converter.TestConverter) ... test: [<Element {http://www.ivoa.net/xml/VOTable/v1.3}VOTABLE at 0x7fa2b99a8dc0>]
```

However, when I attempt to query as below, I get an empty list as the result:

```py
print(f"test: { self.tree('/VOTABLE*') }")
```

I've tried prepending the namespace to VOTABLE as below with no results either:

```py
print(f"test: { self.tree('/{http://www.ivoa.net/xml/VOTable/v1.3}VOTABLE*') }")
```

Can anyone tell me what rookie mistake I am making?

Sample data:

```
<VOTABLE version="1.4" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns="http://www.ivoa.net/xml/VOTable/v1.3"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ivoa.net/xml/VOTable/v1.3 http://www.ivoa.net/xml/VOTable/v1.3">
 <DESCRIPTION>
   VizieR Astronomical Server vizier.u-strasbg.fr
    Date: 2020-11-07T11:43:26 [V1.99+ (14-Oct-2013)]
   Explanations and Statistics of UCDs:         See LINK below
   In case of problem, please report to:    cds-question@unistra.fr
   In this version, NULL integer columns are written as an empty string
   &lt;TD&gt;&lt;/TD&gt;, explicitely possible from VOTable-1.3
 </DESCRIPTION>
 <RESOURCE ID="yCat_3135" name="III/135A">
  ...
 </RESOURCE>
 ...
</VOTABLE>
```

**UPDATE: SOLUTION**

Once drec4s pointed out that I wasn't registering the namespace for the query, I managed to work out what I was doing wrong. Here is the working block of code:

```py
        parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_comments=True, encoding="UTF-8", no_network=True, recover=True)
        root = etree.XML(self.text, parser=parser)
        self.tree = etree.XPathElementEvaluator(root)
        self.tree.register_namespace("n", "http://www.ivoa.net/xml/VOTable/v1.3")
        test = self.tree("/n:VOTABLE/n:DESCRIPTION/text()")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `xpath` method, but you also need to include a `namespace` map to the method:

```
from lxml import etree
from io import StringIO

xmldoc =  StringIO("""
<VOTABLE version="1.4" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns="http://www.ivoa.net/xml/VOTable/v1.3"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ivoa.net/xml/VOTable/v1.3 http://www.ivoa.net/xml/VOTable/v1.3">
 <DESCRIPTION>
   VizieR Astronomical Server vizier.u-strasbg.fr
    Date: 2020-11-07T11:43:26 [V1.99+ (14-Oct-2013)]
   Explanations and Statistics of UCDs:         See LINK below
   In case of problem, please report to:    cds-question@unistra.fr
   In this version, NULL integer columns are written as an empty string
   &lt;TD&gt;&lt;/TD&gt;, explicitely possible from VOTable-1.3
 </DESCRIPTION>
 <RESOURCE ID="yCat_3135" name="III/135A">
 </RESOURCE>
</VOTABLE>
""")

tree = etree.parse(xmldoc)
root = tree.getroot()
print(root.xpath('//n:DESCRIPTION', namespaces={'n': 'http://www.ivoa.net/xml/VOTable/v1.3'})[0].text)
```

Output:

```
   VizieR Astronomical Server vizier.u-strasbg.fr
    Date: 2020-11-07T11:43:26 [V1.99+ (14-Oct-2013)]
   Explanations and Statistics of UCDs:         See LINK below
   In case of problem, please report to:    cds-question@unistra.fr
   In this version, NULL integer columns are written as an empty string
   <TD></TD>, explicitely possible from VOTable-1.3
```

Comment: Thank you, that did it. Since I was using XPathElementEvaluator, there was no xpath() method, but I registered the namespace and it worked.